# Combo box with icons in windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a combobox alike component that displays list of items with icons?

Comment: Check [this C Sharp Help project](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive280.html) and [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ImageComboBoxControl.aspx) out, they show how to derive from the ComboBoxItem to display an image.