# How to add image/icon with each item in Combo box?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on win form application using C#. I came across a scenario where i need to provide a ComboBox to user. Now in order to make look and feel more appealing, i want to display a small image or icon before each item of that combo box.

I look across some third party controls providing this functionality, but i want to use the default combo box control of visual sutdio.
How do i add image by using the default ComboBox control?

Comment: AFAIK this is not directly possible with the combobox control you will have roll in your custom combobox for this

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232861/combo-box-with-icons-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible with the default combo box control from Windows Forms. You need a custom solution with an owner draw combo. See an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ImageComboBoxControl.aspx).

Comment: This is better as a comment rather than answer

Comment: He doesn't have high enough reputation to add comments.

Comment: I can add comments, that's all right. But what I find funny about SO is the concern people have on the form of the answer, rather than the value of the answer. Like whether it's a comment or an answer, or whether it's a link or just restating everything you can find by following that link. Awesome!